# Transforming SMS conversation to Inbox and Sent Items

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, sms

Is it possible for me to receive the SMS not in a conversation style, but in a traditional way like what NOKIA does? Inbox is separated from the Sent items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pansi SMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pansi.msg) supports inbox-style SMS. In Step 2 of the Setup wizard, you will be asked to choose either:

- Conversations
- Message box - **this is what you want**

[image]

Comment: Master @geffchang, i need at least 15 reputation to vote you up.